# Javascript Top Down Movement Issues

Tags: javascript

I have a question about player movement in a top down game.

The player should be able to smoothly move up, down, left, right, and diagonally. The code I have written works at first, but when you hold down two keys for a long time to make the player move diagonally it immediately transitions from smooth to jittery after about one second of holding down both keys.

Here is the code: I would greatly appreciate any help. Thanks!

```
gameCanvas = document.getElementById("gameCanvas");
gameCanvasContext = gameCanvas.getContext("2d");

gameCanvas.width = window.innerWidth;
gameCanvas.height = window.innerHeight;

window.addEventListener("keydown", handleKeyAction);
window.addEventListener("keyup", handleKeyAction);

playerPosition = {xPosition: gameCanvas.width / 2, yPosition: gameCanvas.height / 2};

var keys = [];

function handleKeyAction(event) {
  if(event.type === "keydown" && !keys.includes(event.keyCode)) {
    keys.push(event.keyCode);
  } else {
    for(var index = 0; index < keys.length; index++) {
      if(keys[index] === event.keyCode) {
        keys.splice(index, 1);
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}

function movePlayer() {
  if(keys.includes(87)) {
    playerPosition.yPosition -= 5;
  } if(keys.includes(65)) {
    playerPosition.xPosition -= 5;
  } if(keys.includes(83)) {
    playerPosition.yPosition += 5;
  } if(keys.includes(68)) {
    playerPosition.xPosition += 5;
  }
}

function drawPlayer() {
  gameCanvasContext.beginPath();
  gameCanvasContext.fillStyle = "#000000";
  gameCanvasContext.arc(playerPosition.xPosition, playerPosition.yPosition, 15, 0, Math.PI * 2);
  gameCanvasContext.fill();
  gameCanvasContext.closePath();
}

function animate() {
  gameCanvasContext.clearRect(0, 0, gameCanvas.width, gameCanvas.height);
  movePlayer();
  drawPlayer();
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}

animate();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your `else` in `handleKeyAction`. It fired the `else` even in situations that should not.

Try this ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/StepBaro/4x4wtvhw/1/)):

```
function handleKeyAction(event) {
  if(event.type === "keydown" && !keys.includes(event.keyCode)) {
    keys.push(event.keyCode);
  } 
  if(event.type === "keyup") {
    for(var index = 0; index < keys.length; index++) {
      if(keys[index] === event.keyCode) {
        keys.splice(index, 1);
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! How were you able to find that bug so quickly? Was it just experience or something else?

Comment: @NaamanSmith Surely with the experience you can find the problem faster :) If I helped you mark the answer as correct!